# Android Map controls are not loaded for the first run

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am developing an android application which uses Map V2 api. I have written all the code which includes permission checking code and a button to Toast the present location.

My problem : For the very first run i.e,. when I am installing the application in my phone, the activity is getting loaded which loads the map but does not show any map controls like zoom-in, zoom-out and zoom to current location. But when I close this application from the running applications and when I reopen, it is working perfectly fine loading all MAP OPTIONS. :(

I want to load all the map options even for the first run i.e,. when I install the application for the first time.

Here is my activity code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.talarir.mapproject.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;


import static android.R.attr.permission;

public class MapActivty extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

protected final static String KEY_LOCATION = "location";


protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;

public GoogleMap map;

protected Location mCurrentLocation;

Button saveTheLocationBtnNonAdmin;

PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
static final Integer GPS_SETTINGS = 0x7;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_activty);

    initializeView();

    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    buildGoogleApiClient();

    setUpMap();

    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();
}


private void setUpMap() {
    ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
}

protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
}

protected void checkLocationSettings() {
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(this);
}


protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i("Map Activity", "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_LOCATION)) {
            // Since KEY_LOCATION was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
            // is not null.
            mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        }

        //updateUI();
    }
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"lat : " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + " \t long : " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapActivty.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest,
            this
    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // Permission Granted
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    askForGPS();
                }
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
            else
            {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}

private void askForGPS() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MapActivty.this, GPS_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}


private void initializeView() {
    saveTheLocationBtnNonAdmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveLocationNonAdmin);

}

public void onClickTheSaveLocationButton(View view) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "hmm : " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude() + " " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updateUI();
    //stopLocationUpdates();
}

/**
 * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            this
    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapActivty.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }

            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        //updateUI();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("Map Activity", "Connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("Map Activity", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            Log.i("Map ACtivity", "All location settings are satisfied.");
            startLocationUpdates();
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            Log.i("Map ACtivity", "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                    "upgrade location settings ");

            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                // in onActivityResult().
                status.startResolutionForResult(MapActivty.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i("Map ACtivity", "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.i("Map ACtivity", "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                    "not created.");
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    //updateUI();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i("Map Activity", "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.i("Map Activity", "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    checkLocationSettings();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
    // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
    // location updates if the user has requested them.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    this.map = map;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                       int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapActivty.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivty.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }

        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


}
}
```

Here is my Layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.talarir.mapproject.NonAdminClasses.MapActivty">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSaveLocationNonAdmin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickTheSaveLocationButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Save U!" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ManiFest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.talarir.mapproject">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.maps.android.utils.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="key" />

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AdminActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NonAdminACtivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AdminClasses.AddMainGroupAdmin" />
    <activity android:name=".AdminClasses.AddSubGroupAdmin" />
    <activity android:name=".NonAdminClasses.MapActivty"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in ADVANCE :)

Comment: Have you tried putting all the map initialisation (from `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` to `map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);`) before this line: `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission...`?

Comment: @antonio   sorry bro. I tried in many ways. But it didn't worked out. I have debugged a lot an have noticed that, for the first run of the application, while requesting the permission it is not going good. I am doing some mistake there. I am not able to find that out. "onRequestPermissionsResult" is the place where my debug is failing at for the first run. As a result the next steps in the onMapReady method is not being executed. This is the information that I have gained after debugging the application for many times.

Answer (score 0):

take permission in `onViewCreated` like this

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment);
    ft.commit();




    if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
    {
        /*ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);*/
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: in if");
    } else {
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: in else");
    }

}
```

and in your `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {

        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        } else if (grantResults.length==0)
        {
            if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            }


    }


}
```

Before applying this code check if your `OnRequestPermission` method is calling and 
 `grantResults.length==0`.This usually happen after first time installation